# How long can Face detection on Android run after call to startFaceDetection?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, face-detection

I have an empty PreviewTexture for the camera I'm using FaceDetection on. I've got a FaceDetectionListener set up and call startFaceDetection after calling startPreview. I print messages to the logcat in the FaceDetectionListener callback. After about 2-3 seconds, I keep getting the 'SurfaceTexture has been abandoned' error on my logcat. After this, I'm assuming face detection stops since I don't see the messages in the logcat I saw before. Everything is at a standstill because the code flow continues after a face has been detected.

So my question is if there are any memory or other limitations that prevent face detection from running infinitely?

Comment: Can't comment specifically on this instance, but most cameras with live preview sensors have a hard limit on how long they can run, in order to protect the sensor from overheating etc.  Perhaps you could detect when the *SurfaceTexture* dies, wait a second or two, and restart it - you risk have a short period when it can't detect faces, but will allow long-running detection without risking the sensor.